# segmented control always return 0

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, indexing, switch-statement, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a TabBar app with a navigation item that includes a `UISegmentedControl`.

I've connected a method when the event "value changed" is caught.

The method always catch 0 as SegmentIndex...

Here's my header file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface GraphNavController : UINavigationController {

    IBOutlet UIImage *image;
    CGPoint gestureStartPoint;
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged;

-(void)journalier;
-(void)mensuel;
-(void)annuel;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@end
```

The method is here :

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{

    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"1");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"3");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

I hope we will find a solution

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible explanation for this problem is that **self.segmentedControl** is nil. Is self.segmentedControl as an IBOutlet? Or created in code? Check if self.segmentedControl == nil.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For my case, NSLog(@"self.segmentedControl == %d", self.segmentedControl); return me 0. segmentedcontrol is an Outlet (I've updated my initial post to show the header ^^)

Comment: 0 is nil. The problem **is** that self.segmentedControl is nil. Have you assigned the IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: wich elements do I have to link??? the BarSegmentedControl with what? sorry... I don't made the link with the outlet !

Comment: I've Linked the Outlet from the GraphNavController to the BarSegmented and it's running... beginner's fault... HUNDRED OF THANKS !!!

Comment: i took unsigned short and store changed segment index in it as it changes. ;) problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fight with the bug of nill UISegmentedControl.

**AND I FOUND THE ANSWER.**

Sometimes you have the same problem but you have all connections in XIB.

**THE PROBLEM:** You have nill in self.segmentedControl.
In most situations when you have everything connected in XIB correct it will also not work.

**THE CAUSE:** Because of difference in studing the Objective-C we use different styles of writing code.

**The Decision**: For example we write in interface **UISegmentedControl *control;**
When you @synthesize how would you do that?
If you write **@synthesize control=_control;** you will always have nill when you write like that **NSLog(@"%i",control.selectedSegmentIndex)**.

So we have the mistake in **@synthesize** or in Code.

Decision

**For thou who write @synthesize control; use control.selectedSegmentIndex**

**For thou who write @synthesize control=_control; use _control.selectedSegmentIndex**

And everything will work correct.